# Adding custom response header in "HTTP Response Headers" module within IIS7 Manager ok to use if cannot access web.config file?

Tags: iis, https, iis-7, http-headers, hsts

I am attempting to insert a custom response header to comply with a requirement to enable HSTS as the current layout is at risk against our cyber security audit.

[I am referencing this previous StackOverflow thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/417173/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-in-iis-7/629594#629594) as the "best answers" suggests to set the custom response header using the IIS7 Manager interface, versus the second "best answer" to be going into the `web.config` file and copy and pasting code into it.

[I tried to follow directions to access using this link, but I did not get far because I do not have `EFTAdHoc` subfolder under `Default Web Site` on step 3.](http://help.globalscape.com/help/archive/eft6-2/mergedprojects/sat/editing_the_configuration_file.htm)

I am curious if it is still ok if I set the custom response header this way:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am curious if it is still ok if I set the custom response header this way:

This dialogue is adding headers for all requests. But in your case, you need slightly different. You need to add HSTS only for HTTPS requests. Answer in this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/417173/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-in-iis-7/629594#629594) which you referred before is correct because it is setting header only if it is HTTPS request.

You can do that with IIS Manager.

1) Go to URL Rewrite
[image]
2) Click Add Rule -> Outbound rules -> Blank rule
3) Fill fields like that:
[image]

Comment: It appears I don't have URL Rewrite under IIS inside IIS Manager. I have ASP, Authentication, CGI, Compression, Default Document, Directory Browsing, Error Pages, FastCGI Settings, Handler Mappings, HTTP Response Headers, ISAPI and CGI Restrictions, ISAPI Filters, Logging, MIME Types, Modules, Output Caching, Request Filtering, Server Certificates and Workers Processes. I will have to download it then I suppose. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Hi Victor, does URL Rewrite come standard with IIS at a certain OS version? If so, which one? I am using Windows Server 2008 R2, but it may have been removed due to my company provisioning these servers and made modifications to what it comes with out of the box.

Comment: You can install it from this link: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you so much for your detailed answer. It was super simple and easy to do, we just passed our security audit on this one thanks to your awesome help. Thanks again and cheers!